# HttpClient 4.2.3 - Connection reset exception

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am developing a app to send https POST request with URL parameters, using Apache HttpClient 4.2.3. I have to send URL parameters in the POST request like "?username=abc". I am getting Connection reset exception. I don't get any clue what thing I have to fix to solve this issue. I would be glad, if someone help me about this issue.

The "Connection reset" exception is thrown when "httpClient.execute(httpPost);" code is executed.

Here is code to get httpClient:

```
    .  .. . . . . .. . . . .
    System.out.println("--Enter HttpClient.getSSLHttpClient--");

    // a trust manager that trusts everything
    X509TrustManager allTrustManager = new AllTrustManager();

    // SSLContext
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { allTrustManager }, null);

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
    Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", port,sslSocketFactory);
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

    ClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);

    //System.out.println("--Exit HttpClient.getSSLHttpClient--");

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm,getHttpParams());

    System.out.println("--Exit HttpClient.getSSLHttpClient--");

    return httpClient;  
    .  .. . . . . .. . . . .



Here is the stake trace:

11:58:27.593 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->https://xyz.com:443
11:58:27.786 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to xyz.com:443
11:58:29.379 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
11:58:29.387 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
11:58:29.387 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:58:29.388 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:58:29.388 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
11:58:29.388 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /user?username=abc&password=123 HTTP/1.1
11:58:29.388 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "POST /user?username=abc&password=123 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Keep-Alive: true[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Accept: text/html[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Host: xyz.com:443[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "[\r][\n]"
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /user?username=abc&password=123 HTTP/1.1
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Keep-Alive: true
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: text/html
11:58:29.389 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 0
11:58:29.390 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: xyz.com:443
11:58:29.390 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
11:58:29.660 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:53007<->xx.xx.xx.xx:443 closed
11:58:29.660 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Closing the connection.
11:58:29.660 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:53007<->xx.xx.xx.xx:443 closed
11:58:29.660 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:53007<->xx.xx.xx.xx:443 shut down
11:58:29.661 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@4f8bc5eb
11:58:29.661 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive for 9223372036854775807 MILLISECONDS
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:522)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
```

Answer (score 1):

At last, I have found the solution. I mentioned that I have used HttpClient 4.2.3. Previously, I used the following code to get HttpPost object:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xyz.com:443/user?username=abc&password=123");
.. . .. . .
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
..  .. . . . .
```

and got "Connection reset" exception.

Then I have removed the port and tried again. Now, I have got the response from the server successfully:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xyz.com/user?username=abc&password=123");
.. . .. . .
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
..  .. . . . .
```

It is working fine but I have still a question:
why I have got response successfully after removing the port?

Comment: because you used a port that is reserved for system use. Try using a big number for the port, like > 1024; even better something very big, say like 3040 and it should work fine.

Comment: I have tried with other site, for example https://accounts.google.com:443, using GET method. I have got the response successfully. I am really confused now, why I need to remove port from the specific site https://xyz.com:443 only to get the response, using POST method.

Comment: port 443 is used by SSH, which is a well known port. Why don't you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @Abraham Nonsense. Your own reference shows that port 443 is used by HTTPS. Why don't you read it yourself? Not that Wikipedia is a normative reference. I would expect to see at least a reference to RFC 1700. In any case using the wrong port at the client does not cause 'connection reset' errors.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem the other day, and I solved it by removing the 443 port.
I still don't understand why it was causing problems. The thing is that if i copy / pasted the url to the browser it works just fine...

Comment: It doesn't make sense. 443 is the default port for HTTPS. Specifying it or not specifying it shouldn't make the slightest difference.